# Can't find any documentation on WM_MOUSEFIRST

Tags: windows, winapi, events, mouseevent, message-queue

I have my custom WndProc which is supposed to handle input depending on if my ImGui menu is open.

```
if (Menu::isOpen) {
    ImGui_ImplWin32_WndProcHandler(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    if    (msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN
        || msg == WM_LBUTTONUP
        || msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK

        || msg == WM_MBUTTONDOWN
        || msg == WM_MBUTTONUP
        || msg == WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK

        || msg == WM_RBUTTONDOWN
        || msg == WM_RBUTTONUP
        || msg == WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK

        || msg == WM_XBUTTONDOWN
        || msg == WM_XBUTTONUP
        || msg == WM_XBUTTONDBLCLK
        || msg == WM_MOUSEFIRST) return 0;
}
return CallWindowProc((WNDPROC)Get().m_ulOldWndProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```

My goal is to prevent ONLY mouse clicks from going to the background if my ImGui is open. I noticed that if I don't prevent WM_MOUSEFIRST from going through, some clicks still occasionally register in the app. I've also noticed that when I do prevent WM_MOUSEFIRST from going through, hovering over stuff in the application doesn't work, which I would like to. I thought that I could fix the problem by checking for something in the wParams or lParams, but I can't find any documentation on those for WM_MOUSEFIRST

Comment: [`WM_MOUSEFIRST == WM_MOUSEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove)

Comment: So it is probably the wParam that caused the click

Comment: Handling `WM_MOUSEMOVE` doesn't magically introduce mouse click messages. Whatever causes the observed result from being different from the expected result is certainly not related to your handling of `WM_MOUSEMOVE`. There's probably a bug in your code. The `(WNDPROC)` cast is a sure way to hide a bug.

Comment: @IInspectable it was not a bug, it was the fact that the application registered WM_MOUSEMOVE as a click IF it had the wParam MK_LBUTTON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After smashing my mouse I found out that the click only registers if the mouse is moving. It was because the application checked if WM_MOUSEMOVE (which is same as WM_MOUSEFIRST) had the wParam MK_LBUTTON set. I simply added. `|| ((msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE) && (wParam != 0))`

Answer (score 12):

`WM_MOUSEFIRST` and `WM_MOUSELAST` aren't message identifiers. They are symbolic constants used to express a range of mouse-related messages. They are useful only to determine, whether any given message falls inside that particular range, e.g.

```cpp
bool is_mouse_msg(uint32_t msg)
{
    return (msg >= WM_MOUSEFIRST) && (msg <= WM_MOUSELAST);
}
```

You'll find similar `WM_XXXFIRST`/`WM_XXXLAST` pairs for many other message types, like `WM_KEYFIRST`/`WM_KEYLAST`, `WM_TABLET_FIRST`/`WM_TABLET_LAST`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, though it seems my problem was in WM_MOUSEMOVE , which is the same number as WM_MOUSEFIRST